# Определить количество возможных падежей

Tags: падежи

С жару, к жару, в жару. Сколько разных падежей можно здесь обнаружить?

Comment: Один, может быть два, а может быть и три.  А Вы-то как полагаете?

Comment: Где родительный, где винительный?  Попробуйте привыкнуть давать полный ответ.

Comment: Родит с жару, винит в жару, дательн к жару, предложн в жару ( в смысле когда температура тела ) может так?

Comment: Вот... Уже ближе к телу.  И замечательно было бы хотя бы небольшую фразу для иллюстрации...  "Пирог - с пылу, с жару", например...

Comment: Гулять в жару, привести к жару, быть в жару

Comment: "Привести к жару"?  Впрочем, наверное, можно.  Ещё здесь: http://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=%22%D0%BA+%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Жар - пироги с пылу с жару (Р.п.), метаться в жару (П.п.), привыкай к жару, грешник (Д.п.).

Жара - в жару (в жаркую погоду) (В.п).

Answer (score 0):

Можно обнаружить 3 падежа. С жару-р.п.,в жару п.п к жару-д.п.

Comment: А вот тут четыре видят))) как быть?